# angular Dynamic html binding with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-components

I am getting HTML data from an API and this Html has two radio buttons and some text. In my app, I am binding this Html in modal by [innerHtml]="example|safeHtml" and when I change the radio button option, I want to get these values on click of modal submit button. Here is my Html:

```
<div class="safeCustody-charge">
<p class="para1">This is to inform you that effective 1 September 2019</p>&nbsp;

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios55" id="exampleRadios1"  value="option1" checked="checked">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
       <span style="color:red">Option 1:</span> I acknowledge the policy change
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios55"  id="exampleRadios2" value="option2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
       <span style="color:red">Option 2:</span> I do not wish to pay
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want: *Which radio button has selected by user?*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale yes i want to get the selected value

Comment: You can use `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale we can use ngmodel here but thanks anyway issue has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Since you're putting the html in with the `[innerHtml]` directive, you cannot use any Angular mechanics do get the values. Try using vanilla js functions, like for example

```js
document.getElementById('exampleRadios1').value
```

You may need to cast the returning element to a `HTMLInputElement` for type checks.

Personally I wouldn't get the HTML from a seperate resource. Instead you could return some JSON from your server, then use some `*ngFor` logic to display the content as needed.

Comment: Hi @Celsiuss, yes I am getting JSON response from the server along with an attribute body and this attribute has Html, now if this is a plain text Html it is working fine and able to show on UI but I have two radion button also now I want to get the value the selected radio button, Any Idea ?